# Subject-verb agreement after "all"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Are the following two sentences correct, considering S-V agreement?

> All she has **are** a house, a car and a job.
>
> All she has **is** a house, a car and a job.

I tend to think the first makes more sense as the items mentioned together form a plural that requires a plural verb. This is even clearer if we reverse the order of the first sentence as follows:

> A house, a car and a job are all she has.

However, for some reason, my mind still accepts **is**. Maybe because it can still regard **all** as a single entity or a group of things taken together.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are correct. 
It is sometimes very effective to use **all** in a cleft structure if you want to focus on one particular thing (meaning *the only thing*,*everything*, *nothing more*). *All* is a pronoun in these sentences. *All (that) I +verb* is actually an object in the front position and the real subject is *delayed* . We find it after *be*. The traditional agreement (a singular noun agrees with a singular and a plural noun with a plural verb form ) is valid. But when *all* is a direct object we can use either a single or a plural verb after the clause. We can consider what "is left" as an entity.The traditional agreement is used more often.

> All (that) I want for Christmas is a new coat.
>   A new coat is all (that) I want for Christmas.
>
> All (that) he had were buckets of water for his severely skinny herd.
>   Buckets of water were all he had.
>
> All I need **is** names and addresses. All I need **are** names and addresses.

Every other use requires a singular verb.

> All (that) I have is yours.

Comment: **All** is never a noun. In this context, it is a pronoun.  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all

Comment: All.
n.
The whole of one's fortune, resources, or energy; everything one has: The brave defenders gave their all.

American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

Comment: Ok, almost never. But definitely not in this case :-)

Comment: @JavaLatte It's neither a noun nor a pronoun. It's *determinative*. One simple reason is an adverb (for example *almost*) can modify *all* here, unlike a noun or a pronoun.

Comment: @Man_From_India that's not true in the case cited in the earlier comment, where it's clearly a *noun*, albeit in a very restrictive usage – see [Merriam-Webster, entry 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all). In the OP's original sentence, *all* does function as a determinative of the missing words *the things* – in fact, its order in the NP means it's a [*predeterminer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners#Universal_determiners).